# VBA IE 11 Outlook How to supress "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab."

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, internet-explorer-11

I have an Outlook VBA script that gets a url from a hyperlink in an email, then opens the url which takes me to a password protected intranet site and downloads a file. The project has been very finicky. It seems to run ok when I run it from excel, but when I run the script from outlook I get the below msg. This includes running the excel script from outlook.

[image: This is the message I am getting.]

I've gone to great lenghts to avoid send keys methods. Does anyone have any ideas how to supress this?

I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357410/bypass-ie-the-webpage-you-are-viewing-pop-up), but I'm not convinced the same rules apply to vba ie automation.

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: What method are you using to close the page/tab/window?

Comment: @thunderframe the tab that causes the msg is closed automatically by the webpage. i don't close it.

Comment: Have you tried identifying the query parameters and URL for submitting the form? Maybe you could achieve the scrape with MSXML instead if automating IE?

Comment: The URL does not asss query parameters. It is a link to a canned report. Msxml does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a shot, it uses windows API functions to first find the window, then sends a message to that window to close it.

```
Option Explicit
Public Const WM_CLOSE = &H10

'Api Declarations
#If VBA7 Then
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#Else
    Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" _
    (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long

    Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessage" (ByVal hwnd As Long, _
    ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, lParam As Any) As Long
#End If

Public Sub CloseWindow()
    Dim Ret        As Long ' A return value
    Dim Windowname As String: Windowname = "Windows Internet Explorer" ' the name of the window you want to close

    Ret = FindWindow(vbNullString, Windowname) ' find the handle of the window
    If Ret <> 0 Then SendMessage Ret, WM_CLOSE, 0&, 0& 'close the window
End Sub
```