# How to avoid "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab".?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

In my JavaScript app I am embedding an ms video(ms stream). It is embedded on a page but still have to sign in into ms.  It shows a message:  "The webpage you are viewing is trying to close the tab".  This is in internet explorer 11. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/357410/bypass-ie-the-webpage-you-are-viewing-pop-up) link, it might have what you need.

Something that stood out to me was what [d-coder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/900390/d-coder) said:

> In the opened popup write following

```
var objWin = window.self;
objWin.open('','_self','');
objWin.close();
```